# Finding nonzero points in a wide multidimensional space (but bounded)

Tags: regions

I have a quite complicated region over 5D, and I want to know whether it is nonzero over a given interval. I don't even need to know the points (although it would be nice), but I would need to know whether is completely empty or there is some hope still. I have foun
nd some kind of answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158311/implicitregion-emptiness-check) which kind of satisfies me, but what if I would like to check on a limited space? - I suppose it would be faster.

Comment: It is necessary to publish the definition of the region in 5D and code with an example.

Comment: I don't see how that would help. Just imagine something like ImplicitRegion[fn[a,b,c,d,e],{a,b,c,d,e}]

Comment: I will show how that can help. Please post  the definition of the region in 5D and code with an example.